# "Не" с наречием на "‑о"

Tags: орфография, грамматика, частица-не, слитно-раздельно, наречия

1. Сгруппировать данные, которые связаны с массивом, но имеют **несильно** значимую связь с ним.
2. Сгруппировать данные, которые связаны с массивом, но имеют **не сильно** значимую связь ним.

Здесь скорее отрицается сильная значимость, нежели утверждается слабая. Подходит второй вариант. Но есть два но:

1) Нет противопоставления и не подразумевается.

2) "Не сильно" не является сказуемым (предикативом), а сказуемое "имеет" отрицания не содержит. Или наречие с "не" со значением отрицания необязательно должно быть сказуемым, то есть являться предикативом ("до остановки не далеко"), чтобы писаться раздельно? Другими словами, работает ли правило даже в том случае, если наречие с "не", имеющее значение отрицания, не входит в состав сказуемого?

Comment: _Сгруппировать данные, которое связаны..._  Наверно, **которые**?

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова Это опечатка. Исправил.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Вот предположение автора вопроса:** *Или наречие с "не" со значением отрицания необязательно должно быть сказуемым, то есть являться предикативом ("до остановки не далеко"), чтобы писаться раздельно?*

**Но откуда это предположение взялось** — вот что интересно.

В грамматике существует такое понятие, **как общее и частное отрицание.** Если частица  НЕ относится к предикативу, то это называется общим отрицанием.  Но частица НЕ может относиться к любому слову (а также словосочетанию), и это будет частное отрицание.  В этом случае также приходится различать слитное и раздельное написание НЕ.

**Послушаем Г. Р. Державина:** *Как сон, как сладкая мечта, Исчезла и моя уж младость; **Не сильно нежит красота**, Не столько восхищает радость...*

**Посмотрим у Розенталя:** http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=74#pp74

Примечание. В некоторых случаях возможно двоякое толкование текста и, как следствие, двоякое написание частицы НЕ с наречием. Ср.: редактор уехал **ненадолго** (‘на короткое время’),
редактор уехал **не надолго** (‘не на продолжительное время’).

**Заглянем в Нацкорпус:** По его словам, действия Минфина **не сильно повлияют** на рынок. Я бы **не сильно переживал** за японцев, работать они умеют.Там и сейчас **не сильно жарко**. Даже **не сильно ржавый** бак в интернете можно найти за две тысячи.

**ВЫВОД**

1) Во всех приведенных примерах частица НЕ не относится к предикативу, но пишется раздельно.

2) Есть, правда, одна хитрость, на которую не все обращают внимание. Чтобы обстоятельственное наречие писалось раздельно, на него должно падать ударение.

Сравнить: *Я  **негромко** свИстнул, подзывая собАку. Он **не грОмко**  сказал, но все услышали.* В безударной позиции обстоятельственное наречие обычно пишется слитно.

Comment: Вы отлично уловили, что именно не понимает автор вопроса, и дали ему нужную информацию. Спасибо вам. "Даже не сильно ржавый бак в интернете можно найти за две тысячи" — прямо как наш случай.

Answer (score 2):

> Здесь скорее отрицается сильная значимость, нежели утверждается
>   слабая. Подходит второй вариант. Но есть два но:
>
> 1) Нет противопоставления и не подразумевается.
>
> 2) "Не сильно" не является сказуемым (предикативом), а сказуемое
>   "имеет" отрицания не содержит.

Если есть отрицание качества, другие условия уже не обязательны, так что если Вы считаете, что здесь отрицается сильная значимость, смело можно писать раздельно с НЕ.

Comment: Не могли бы дать ссылку на какой‑нибудь источник, подтверждающий ваше мнение? Из того, что подходит для нашего случая, я нашёл только правило про противопоставление и про безличное предложение (т.  е. "сильно" должно быть предикативным наречием, или словом категории состояния, которое в предложении является сказуемым).

Comment: http://www.old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=81 - смотрите Примечание.до ближайшей остановки автобуса отсюда недалеко (утверждается, что близко)
до ближайшей остановки автобуса отсюда не далеко (отрицается, что далеко)

Comment: У Лопатина то же самое. Таким образом, пишущий должен отдавать себе отчет в том, чтб он хочет выразить: отрицание признака — и тогда написать не отдельно от следующего слова (напр.: он не здоров, не важно, не редки случаи, не случайно, не существенно, не удивительно, не демократическим путём) или утверждение признака — и тогда написать не слитно (ср.: он нездоров, нередки случаи, неважно, неслучайно, несущественно, неудивительно, недемократическим путем). От выбора написания будет зависеть и понимание написанного читающими

Comment: У Розенталя «не далеко» предикатив, а не наречие. В ваших примерах: полное прилагательное («не демократическим путём»), краткое прилагательное («он не здоров»), предикатив («не удивительно слышать»), наречие, которое относится напрямую к сказуемому («увеличился не существенно»). Везде не та синтаксическая функция, что у нас. Везде отрицание имеет центральную смысловую позицию — содержится в сказуемом или во второстепенном члене, относящимся к сказуемому.

Comment: О какой синтаксич. функции вы говорите? "...имеют не сильно значимую связь ним" - это тоже состав сказуемого. Имеют связь=связаны (фразеологизм) - сказуемое. Какую связь - значимую - определение, (в какой степени?) не сильно - обстоятельство меры и степени.

Answer (score 1):

Разумеется,  допускается раздельное написание ***не сильно ***, так как это наречие имеет ряд  **с градацией признака**: сильно — не сильно (средняя величина) — несильно (слабо) — слабо. Таким образом,  форма написания здесь имеет **смысловое значение**.

Но я думаю, что ***сильно значимый*** — это не совсем корректное сочетание (как-то оно не воспринимается на слух, да и в Нацкорпусе не встречается). И это неудивительно, ведь мы же не говорим: *это для меня сильно значит*.

Возможный вариант: ***Сгруппировать данные, которые связаны с массивом, но имеют не существенно значимую связь с ним.***

Другие варианты наречий: не много, не особо, не очень.

Кроме того, здесь повтор слова: **связаны, связь**.

Поэтому остановимся на таком варианте: ***Сгруппировать данные, которые связаны с массивом, но не в значительной степени.***